# golang: cgo extern is not working

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to run cgo for golang with following example (given at [go-wiki -> Global Functions](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo#Global_functions)):

`foo.go` file:

```
package gocallback

import "fmt"

/*
#include <stdio.h>
extern void ACFunction();
*/
import "C"

//export AGoFunction
func AGoFunction() {
        fmt.Println("AGoFunction()")
}

func Example() {
        C.ACFunction()
}
```

`foo.c` file:

```
#include "_cgo_export.h"
void ACFunction() {
    printf("ACFunction()\n");
    AGoFunction();
}
```

While running this example, I am getting following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
/tmp/go-build770916112/command-line-arguments/_obj/foo.cgo2.o: In function    `_cgo_3234419c4c2a_Cfunc_ACFunction':
./foo.go:36: undefined reference to `ACFunction'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not able to trace this down. Why `ACFunction` is `undefined`? or Am I missing something?

`go version`:
go version go1.1.2 linux/386

Comment: Your cut-down example seems to compile okay for me.  Your `foo.go` file doesn't have 36 lines though, so is it possible that the error exists in some of the code you've removed?

Comment: No, I have not removed any of code. That line part also made me confused. How do you compile cgo? I am using `go run foo.go`. Is there any specific gcc version required or 32-bit/64-bit machine or anything?

Comment: I used `go build packagename`.  I tested both the 1.1.2 and 1.2 releases on Linux/amd64.

Comment: Hmmm. That was the problem. `go run` doesn't work. `go build packagename` works as expected. Thanks for your pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the question comments, it seems that you were trying to build and run the program with `go run foo.go`.

This fails with a `go run: cannot run non-main package` error, but converting the package name to `main` and adding a `main` function does reproduce the error in the question.  This seems to be because it is trying to compile only the `foo.go` file and not the companion `foo.c` file.

If you instead place the files in a directory under `$GOPATH/src` and use `go build packagename` to build the program, it should successfully build all the source files in the package.